# Some methods in class do not recognize that instance of MKMapView already exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to turn on User Tracking Mode for my MKMapView. The MKMapView is part of the storyboard, so I believe it is automatically initialized. When I run the debugger on the `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`, it prints the address of the MKMapView, so it seems to be initialized. Here are my methods in my FirstViewController class:

```
    #import "FirstViewController.h"
    #import "Options.h"
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @interface FirstViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation FirstViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        self.currentMap.delegate = self;
        [appDelegate.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        appDelegate.locationManager.distanceFilter = 20.0;

    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewDidAppear:NO];
        if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cannot Access Location"
                                                message:@"Please allow Location Services in Settings."
                                                delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        self.currentMap.showsUserLocation = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"mapLocation"];
    }

    - (void)changeTracking {
        if (self.currentMap.userTrackingMode == MKUserTrackingModeNone)
        {
            [self.currentMap setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
        }
        else if (self.currentMap.userTrackingMode == MKUserTrackingModeFollow)
        {
            [self.currentMap setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

When I call `[appdelegate.firstViewController changeTracking]` from another class, the `changeTracking` method executes, but it thinks that `self.currentMap` is `nil`. So when it changes the user tracking mode, it doesn't actually have any effect on the map that is recognized by `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`. Why do the first two methods recognize the instance of the MKMapView but `changeTracking` does not?

Comment: Are you perhaps setting the map view user tracking mode to `.FollowWithHeading`? Because if that's your initial state, your `-changeTracking` only handles the other two modes and would never execute an `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a better handle one what's going on.

Do you have an outlet connected to your map view?

Add an NSLog to your viewDidLoad method and log self.currentMap. Also log the address of self.

Then, in your other methods, also log the address of self (using the %X format string, and casting self to unsigned long).

My guess: Either your outlet link is broken or you are creating multiple instances of your class without realizing it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Yes, I have an outlet connected to my map view. I added NSLog of self and self.currentMap to each method, and the address of self was the same for all three. The address of self.currentMap was the same for the first two methods, and the address of self.currentMap for changeTracking was null. I don't think my outlet is broken because the map works properly in the simulator as far as turning showsUserLocation on and off, but the tracking mode does not change because changeTracker runs on a null self.currentMap.